# SQL Server Replication, Consolidation

Tags: sql-server, replication, consolidation

How do I consolidate multiple publications into 1 consolidated table on the subscriber? For example. Consider a very simple sales model where we replicate sales data from the stores to the central office.

```
Store 1 Sales Table  
=====================  
Item     Qty      Amt  
=====================  
111       2     10.00  
222       1      7.00  
333       1     12.00  

Store 2 Sales Table
=====================
Item     Qty      Amt
=====================
111       2     18.00
222       1     13.00
333       1      4.00
```

How do I replicate these two sales publications from the publisher to ONE consolidated sales table at the subscriber:

```
Central Office
==============================
Store   Item     Qty       Amt
==============================
1        111       2     10.00
1        222       1      7.00
1        333       1     12.00
2        111       2     18.00
2        222       1     13.00
2        333       1      4.00
```

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you working with? There are some significant differences with Replication, between certain editions.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Keep the existing table unchanged", default is drop and recreate.

Fast search, old example but seems valid ->  [sql preformance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/multiple_publishers_replication_p1.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! One other thing. Do you know of a way I can actually inject a user defined column into the article somewhere before it leaves the publisher? I need to add a sinature to each article so I can tell which publisher it came from.

Comment: Don't think there are any guitools for this, you will need to dig deeper into t-sql replication procedures "replication views" or "filter publish data".